# Content observer is being called even if the Contacts are not changed

Tags: android, contentobserver

I am facing a problem that is strange, i am using the `ContentObserver`to catch the changes in the contacts, but the problem is that the `onchange()` method is called even if i am not making any changes. Here is my code :

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, new MyCOntentObserver());

public class MyCOntentObserver extends ContentObserver{
        public MyCOntentObserver() {
            super(null);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
            Log.e("","~~~~~~"+selfChange);
        }  

        @Override
        public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
            Log.e("","~~~~~~ Change");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

any one can help?
thanks in advance

Comment: when is it being called then?

Comment: it is being called at any time, iam not using the device any it is being called, it is also called when the device syncs with the gmail account

Comment: @Josephus Villarey @AnasBakez change your `URI` to **ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI** and set `notifyForDescendents` to **false**

Comment: ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI and setting notifyForDescendents to false, doesn't resolve the issue. I know the question is old, but is there any other work around?

Answer (score 0):

The `registerContentObserver` method accepts a boolean `notifyForDescendents` variable, which you're setting to true. Maybe set that to false?

Otherwise maybe some background task is messing with your observer. :)

Comment: Check notifyForDescendents Documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver(android.net.Uri, boolean, android.database.ContentObserver)

Comment: How can i Know what is calling the OnChange method?