# ContentObserver for contact update manually

Tags: android, contactscontract

I have registered a `ContentObserver` from service and I get the `onchange()` function when there is update in phone like call or contact update. But I want the `onchange()` function to be called only when add, update or delete happens. But I don't want when call is incoming or outgoing. So can anybody tell me which `URI` I can register in `contentObserver`?  My code is here

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true,new Contact_change());
```

and Contact_change.java class is like

```
public class Contact_change extends ContentObserver{

  public Contact_service() {
    super(null);
  }

  @Override
  public void onChange(boolean selfChange){
    Log.i("contact_service","onchange");
    Super.onChange(selfChange);
   }

 @Override   
 public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
  return true;
  }

}
```

**Edit:**
 I have one more problem is that after stop the service if I made change in contact then also `onchange()` function is called. So how can I stop that or un register the `contentobserver`.

Comment: i don't think this is possible. the time of last call is a field of the Contact, therefore changing it is changing the Contact

Comment: Is it ant other way for get notification of changes in contact?Because i want to synchronize the contacts with my application.

Comment: I don't think it is really a problem if you receive extra notifications for event you don't need.

Comment: i have problem because even if the contact is not updated but call is incoming or outgoing and the onchange() is called then also i consider as contacts are updated and then i will write all contacts from phone to database.So it is worth case.

Comment: but it doesn't do any harm to your application.

Comment: it will not harm my application but the performance will be decrease bcz if 1000 contacts are store from phone to database then it will take 5 minutes..and end user point of view it will worth to stay idle in that case

Comment: then you should consider not storing contacts in your own database. what reason do you have to?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16180/discussion-between-nency-and-njzk2)

Answer (score 0):

I used the **ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI** as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718181/content-observer-is-bieng-called-even-if-the-contacts-are-not-changed?rq=1#comment13921666_10718181).

And also you could set a threshold_time like the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10752736/944070)

Its a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

In order to stop receiving notifications from ContentObserver, you must unregister it.

Create an instance of ContentObserver which you can use later to register/unregister.

```
Contact_change changeObserver = new Contact_change();
```

Register observer:

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true,changeObserver);
```

Unregister observer:

```
getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(changeObserver);
```